# Can't see pod logs in Stackdriver UI for cluster deployed on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, elasticsearch, google-kubernetes-engine, google-stackdriver

I deployed an Elasticsearch cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine.
I am able to view logs of specific pods with the 'kubectl logs' command from my PC.

```
>kubectl logs es-data-0
...
[2018-06-18T07:35:11,220][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [es-data-0] [gc][4510405] overhead, spent [290ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2018-06-18T09:48:19,194][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [es-data-0] [gc][4518376] overhead, spent [366ms] collecting in the last [1.1s]
[2018-06-18T10:01:49,344][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [es-data-0] [gc][4519183] overhead, spent [641ms] collecting in the last [1s]
```

I followed this tutorial to deploy a ConfigMap & DaemonSet for Stackdriver logging:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-stackdriver/

the fluentd pods are running:

`>kubectl get pods
NAME                                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cerebro-59648dc47c-vr964                         1/1       Running   0          25d
es-client-7bff44b8f5-2wqcs                       1/1       Running   0          12d
es-client-7bff44b8f5-vnrhg                       1/1       Running   0          12d
es-data-0                                        1/1       Running   0          52d
es-data-1                                        1/1       Running   0          52d
es-data-2                                        1/1       Running   0          52d
es-master-6bf767f949-8fpjl                       1/1       Running   0          52d
es-master-6bf767f949-brjpq                       1/1       Running   0          52d
es-master-6bf767f949-gx2jp                       1/1       Running   0          52d
fluentd-gcp-v2.0-7mncl                           1/1       Running   0          43m
fluentd-gcp-v2.0-rsfmc                           1/1       Running   0          43m
fluentd-gcp-v2.0-tbh9t                           1/1       Running   0          43m
kibana-595858b4b7-5npcr                          1/1       Running   0          52d
nginx-ingress-controller-86c8447687-z4rjq        1/1       Running   2          52d
nginx-ingress-default-backend-6664bc64c9-q2hnm   1/1       Running   338        52d`
`>kubectl get ds --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                       DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                                  AGE
default       fluentd-gcp-v2.0           3         3         3         3            3           beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true       44m
kube-system   fluentd-gcp-v2.0.10        3         3         3         3            3           beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true       52d
kube-system   metadata-proxy-v0.1        0         0         0         0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/metadata-proxy-ready=true   52d
kube-system   nvidia-gpu-device-plugin   0         0         0         0            0           <none>                                         52d`

The ConfigMap is present:

```
>kubectl get cm
NAME                              DATA      AGE
cerebro-configmap                 1         52d
curator-config                    2         6d
fluentd-gcp-config                4         47m
ingress-controller-leader-nginx   0         52d
nginx-ingress-controller          1         52d
```

Finally, I proceeded to Logs Viewer Page, where I selected "GKE Container":
https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer

Unfortunately, I do not see any logs from any pods. As mentioned previously, when using "kubcetl logs" command I can view logs from all the pods from my PC.

Answer (score 1):

- Need to make sure the cluster is set up with Stackdriver logging/monitoring enabled.
- Following the mentioned [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-stackdriver/), you should have a pod named counter. If you run:

$ kubectl logs counter # Are you able to see the output for that pod?

- If you intend to customize Stackdriver Logs for Kubernetes Engine with Fluentd, this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/customizing-stackdriver-logs-fluentd) suggests to first create the cluster service account and assign required roles. Next, the cluster is created with "no-enable-cloud-logging"; and, deploying the Fluentd daemonset.
- Trying the advanced filter like below should help:

resource.type="container"

resource.labels.pod_id="es-data-0"